# How can I change ProjectSettings > Graphics > Transperency Sort Axis via script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have to change transparency sort axis with script on some scenes. One of my scene is isometric but other one is plain2D. I have to switch between (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) sort axis.

How can I reach and change this settings with script?

Does it work on Android devices too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use
Camera.transparencySortMode, Camera.transparencySortAxis and GraphicsSettings.transparencySortMode.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-transparencySortAxis.html